# How to create Typescript Map without sharing between Express Requests

Tags: typescript, caching

I created a static Map in Typescript which stores Mongo DB documents as a Cache( Because I could avoid multiple Mongo DB requests for retrieving same items as part of single request). I made this Map specifically "static" because i could access this cache throughout my application ( I would be doing some computations over the data i had in my cache).

I will have around 60K documents in total to be retrieved from Mongo DB and computation takes some time may be around 15–30 seconds. For each request, i would be expecting different documents will be retrieved based on given input.

I was expecting that Map would be created newly for each request, so that no clash of cached items would happen. But, as i created the Map as "static", items captured in cache are alive from start of server till stop/restart of the server. Because of this, data between parellel requests are mixed and resulting in invalid/incorrect results.

Is there a way to create a Map in typescript without sharing between Express Requests, but in a way that Map to be shared between all my classes/files in my typescript application, as i do some update over data in classes ?

Comment: use [`res.locals`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) that's what it's there for

Comment: But, how can i access my Map in all other classes/files ?

My endpoint method looks as below.

@Post()
 public async getData( @Body() project: empId): Promise<any> {
              return connector.getData(empId);
}